# python pandas による日付処理

Tags: python, pandas

pandasで日付の処理をしており、該当する日付がなければ新しい行を加えるという処理をしようとしています。
そこで次のようなコードを書きました。
リスト内には存在するのにin演算子には引っかからないという現象が起きてしまい、原因がさっぱりわかりません。もしよろしければ原因を教えてください。

```
def complement_date(self,pandas_arr):
    keys = pandas_arr.keys()
    dates = pandas_arr[keys[0]]# date info in first index
    dateidx = START# START = datetime.datitme(2013,8,1,0,0)
    while END>=dateidx:
        if not pd.to_datetime(dateidx) in dates:
            pdb.set_trace()
            tmp = pd.Series([dateidx,0],index=keys)
            pandas_arr = pandas_arr.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
        dateidx = dateidx + DAY# DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return pandas_arr
```

[image: デバッグ画面]

Comment: pdはpandas の略です
(import pandas as pd)

Comment: # START = datetime.datitme(2013,8,1,0,0)
=># START = datetime.datetime(2013,8,1,0,0)

Comment: `dates` が `pandas` の dataframe 型だからではないでしょうか。`in dates` では `dates` の index(`dates.keys()`) と比較しているのではないかと思います。なので、`... in dates.values` としてみると良いのではないかと。

Comment: うーん。。。今それを試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。
アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` は　`Index` との比較になるためです。

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-01-05', freq='D'))
dates
# 0   2011-01-01
# 1   2011-01-02
# 2   2011-01-03
# 3   2011-01-04
# 4   2011-01-05
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

t = pd.Timestamp('2011-01-01')
t == dates[0]
# True

t in dates
# False

0 in dates
# True
```

値に含まれるかは以下で確認できます。

```
(t == dates).any()
# True
```

---

コメントに対する追記:

> t in dates.values #False の解釈

まず、`dates.values` は `numpy.ndarray` 型を返します。そのため、以下の記載は `pandas` ではなく `NumPy` の挙動に関する説明になります。

```
dates.values
# array(['2011-01-01T09:00:00.000000000+0900',
#        '2011-01-02T09:00:00.000000000+0900',
#        '2011-01-03T09:00:00.000000000+0900',
#        '2011-01-04T09:00:00.000000000+0900',
#        '2011-01-05T09:00:00.000000000+0900'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

type(dates.values)
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

`numpy.ndarray` は `in` 演算子をサポートしています。`NumPy` の日時型である `numpy.datetime64`を渡せば期待通り動きます。

```
import numpy as np

np.datetime64('2011-01-01T09:00:00.000000000+0900') in dates.values
# True
```

`pandas` の `Timestamp` 型から `numpy.datetime64` 型への変換は `asm8` プロパティで可能です。そのため、 `in` を使う場合は下のようになります。

```
t.asm8
# numpy.datetime64('2011-01-01T09:00:00.000000000+0900')

t.asm8 in dates.values
# True
```

Comment: 丁寧な解説ありがとうございます。
最後のコードは参考にさせていただきます。
      `t in dates.values  #False`
上で他の方にコメントいただいたのですが、
これについての解釈も教えていただけると幸いです

Comment: @swdrsk 型が違うためでした。`date.values` は pandas の array object なので、`pd.to_datetime(dateidx) in dates.tolist()` とすべきでした。もしくは、swdrsk さんがした様に、`pd.to_datetime(dateidx) in list(dates)` とします。

Comment: @argus pandasのarray objectはin演算子に対応してないんですね,,,面倒くさいですね。ご教授ありがとうございます。

Comment: ``t in dates.values`` について 回答に追記しました。

Comment: @sinhrks 詳しい解説大変ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。

Comment: 私の権限では 下の回答にコメントできなかったためこちらに追記します。

``__contains__`` の処理を変更すると ``pandas`` の処理が壊れますので絶対に止めてください。影響範囲は調査する気にならないほど大きいです。※申し遅れましたが、私は``pandas`` 開発チームのメンバーです。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

原因はいまだにわかりませんが
   dates = pandas_arr[keys[0]]# date info in first index
の部分を
   dates = list(pandas_arr[keys[0]])
としてやるとうまくいったようです。
元のコードだとlist型ではなく1列のpandasのDataFrame型ができるだけのようですね
動作原理がわかる方いらっしゃればご教授下さいm(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

> 私の権限では 下の回答にコメントできなかったためこちらに追記します。 **contains** の処理を変更すると pandas の処理が壊れますので絶対に止めてください。影響範囲は調査する気にならないほど大きいです。※申し遅れましたが、私はpandas 開発チームのメンバーです。

何だか怒られてしまいましたので、`in` 演算子の override ではなく、新たに演算子を作ってみました。

# `dateidx in list(dates)` とすれば良いだけのことなのですが(苦笑)

まず、`Infix` クラスを定義して `|in_df|` 演算子を作ります。

```
class Infix:
  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function
  def __call__(self, value1, value2):
    return self.function(value1, value2)
  def __or__(self, other):
    return self.function(other)
  def __ror__(self, other):
    return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))

in_df = Infix(lambda item, obj: item in obj.tolist())
```

実際に試してみます。

```
> dateidx = datetime.datetime(2013,8,1,0,0)
> dateidx
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0)

> dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2013-08-01', '2013-08-05', freq='D'))
> dates
0   2013-08-01
1   2013-08-02
2   2013-08-03
3   2013-08-04
4   2013-08-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]

> dateidx in dates
False

> dateidx |in_df| dates
True
```

<strike>`in` 演算子の実体である `__contains__`(special method)を再定義するという方法もあります。</strike>

```
> dateidx = datetime.datetime(2013,8,1,0,0)
> dateidx
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0)

> dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2013-08-01', '2013-08-05', freq='D'))
> dates
0   2013-08-01
1   2013-08-02
2   2013-08-03
3   2013-08-04
4   2013-08-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]

> dateidx in dates
False

> type(dates)
pandas.core.series.Series

> pd.core.series.Series.__contains__ = lambda self, item: item in self.tolist()
> dateidx in dates
True
```

ただし、再定義をしてしまうと `pandas.core.series.Series` オブジェクトに対する `in` 演算子本来の使い方(data frame の index を対象)ができなくなります。

```
> 1 in dates
False # 再定義していない場合は True となる
```